# How to set the button fit the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a layout were the top portion is for Imageview and bottom portion for the button .I used the weight property to set the button and the Image in a fixed ratio.But I am not able to set bottom button so fill the hole content.I want the button to be in 50-50 ratio.Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: weights are supposed to be distributed within the same parent. what you have written is basically like giving the same weight to the two buttons inside the LinearLayout. but the LinearLayout its self is not assigned any weight. Also it's not very clear what you are trying to acomplish. "portion" is not very specific. Maybe you should draw your desired layout and post it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set bottom button to fit the content horizontally, Linearlayout should be made to match_parent.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it work just check code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:text="New Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:text="New Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```